# How to start views list at specific ID

Tags: 7, views

I have a list of images(nodes) displaying horizontally and I would like to start from a certain id in this list. The way I have it now it starts at most recent added image(node).

Is there a way to start at a specific id in views?

NOTES:  Would like it to look like the second image on page load. You can see in the first image there is white space to the left. I want this to be filled by an image. The navigation is fixed.

[image: On page load. Positon of images]

[image: After scroll horizontally.]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest perhaps using a Nodequeue - http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue.

This way you can order the images in whichever order you like.

Alternatively, if it is just one node that you want to appear first and then sort by something else you could perhaps utilise the 'sticky' feature?

OR do you want the order to start from ID 5 and continue 6, 7, 8 etc?

Comment: I have updated the post with some photos to better understand my question. Thank you for pointing me to Nodequeue as well.